# BLE Device with Haptic Feedback

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, vibration, haptic-feedback, rapid-prototyping

Is there an off-the-shelf beacon I can just buy that also has support for triggering Vibration / Haptic Motor over BLE? Amazon / whatever links are welcome.

Context: I'd like to trigger vibration from iOS in a small independent device. BLE seems ideal as I need to support more than one and all devices should be within range. I'm trying to rapidly prototype something instead of cranking out my own HW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For prototyping you may be able to use a few sub-$20 Xiaomi Mi Band devices (or Band 2 which should be under $30 and has a screen). And then use API like this to trigger vibration: https://github.com/betomaluje/Mi-Band

They both can be removed from the wristband and look like a 2 cm long pill, and last weeks on a charge with normal use, maybe months when not counting steps.